# Browser's memory keeps increasing when using React-engine & React-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-engine

I'm writing Isormophic Web Application by using React-engine & React-router. Before upgrading, my application is running well with the following configuration.

"react": "^0.14.8",
"react-dom": "^0.14.6",
"react-engine": "^3.4.1",
"react-router": "^1.0.3"

Recently, I've upgraded my system to use official React with the following configuration, and I observed my app become slower and slower when running on browser after every click I made on ReactRouter.Link. I've opened Google Chrome Debugger for investigation, then I see usage memory keep increasing after every click.

"react": "^15.2.1",
"react-dom": "^15.2.1",
"react-engine": "^4.0.0",
"react-router": "^2.5.2"

Have anyone faced the similar problem? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: There's been **a lot** of changes since versions you used were released. Can you paste relevant code?

Comment: Thank Chris for the response. I even observed the problem in the sample code of React-engine: https://github.com/paypal/react-engine/tree/master/example. Do you have any idea?